# How to roll back if I am not used begin transaction in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query like this:

```
update Staff 
set staff_Name = 'jas' 
where staff_id = 7
```

I am not using any `begin transaction` , I just execute this query.

In this case, is there any way to rollback?

Comment: If you're *executing* the query then killing the connection should force a roll back. If you've *executed* the query, then it's time to find your backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use **implicit transactions** for this.. 
try this...

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON

update Staff set staff_Name='jas' where staff_id=7

ROLLBACK
```

As you request-- You can SET this setting ( `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`) from a stored procedure by setting that stored procedure as the start up procedure.But SET IMPLICIT TRANSACTION ON command is connection specific. So any connection other than the one which running the start up stored procedure will not benefit from the setting you set.

Comment: this is working fine,,but i want to know is there any way to manuallly set IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS

Comment: in example,,i can able to create a table manually and through SQL.like that now you set IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON through sql,,i want to we can set this manually..?

Comment: i mean while opening SQLSERVER default i want to  get IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON

Comment: Transactions are meant to be used only for changes made from code. You don't use transactions when working in Microsoft SQL Management Studio designer. If you want to rollback changes made using designer you could try to use database backup/restore operations.

Comment: You can SET this setting from a stored procedure by setting that stored procedure as the start up procedure.But SET IMPLICIT
TRANSACTION ON command is **connection specific**. So any connection other than the one which running the start up stored procedure will not benefit from the setting you set.

Comment: so i can understand there is now way to set manually this right?

Comment: Yes.. try that but there are some limitations

Answer (score 1):

It is imposible to rollback query if you haven't started transaction, sorry.

You could get your data back only if you have backup of the database.

For future it might be a good idea to use implicit transactions using `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` command.

Also, you should check out [SSMS Tools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/). They offer neat feature - automatically put transaction statements in every new query editor just so you don't forget to use implicit transaction.